# What's the meaning of `transparent` in CSS background property?

Tags: css, background-color

What does this class say? What is transparent doing here in background?

```
background: url("../images/abc.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

Will the browser convert a jpg image into transparent? But aren't only pngs transparent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

background is a short-cut in CSS that can be used to set multiple background properties at once. Here's the long form of the same code:

```
background-image: url("../images/abc.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0 0;
background-color: transparent;
```

The background image isn't being set to transparent--the background color is. What this means is if the background image doesn't load or take up the full element, a transparent background color will be used instead.

Answer (score 4):

> How can a jpg image be transparent?

It can't, at least not directly. You can achieve that in a web page by setting the `opacity` for an (entire) element.

> What does this class say?

That's a rule, not a class. CSS doesn't have anything called "a class" (although it comes close with "class selectors").

> What is transparent doing here in background?

When the `background` shorthand property is expanded, `transparent` is the value of `background-color` (i.e. the colour that will be used for the background before the image loads (and if the image fails to load). Since it also says `repeat-x`, if the element is taller than the image, the area not covered by the image will show the background colour.

Answer (score 2):

it's not the image that is transparent. it's means element has no background color behind the image. meaning:

```
background: #333 url('image.jpg') no-repeat;
```

will give you an element with a gray background where it extends beyond the image size.
google "css background"

If you indeed need transparency, use opacity on the element http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp
however that will make whole image semi transparent, so you'll need to play with separating some elements.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent just means that the background color will be transparent. 
Not the image itself.
If you would like transparency in images. You can use opacity(not supported in ie) or pngs and gifs.